# Place div at bottom of each printed page

Tags: html, css

I am using a website (bloomerang.co) to create custom letters in batches. They have a basic html editor that allows basic formatting. (However, they allow direct editing to the html.)
When creating the letters, it seemingly creates one large document with all the letters combined and then prints it with page breaks after each letter.

My problem is that I need a specific div at the bottom of each page which holds custom information for that page.

I've tried absolute and fixed positioning (by editing the html directly), however, this puts them all at the bottom of the *last* page! (I am assuming that the reason is because it is one long document and not separate ones.)

Is there a way with css to force a div (e.g. with class "bot") to be at the bottom of its printed page?

Comment: Can you please give your code in the snippet?

Comment: I don't have the code of the document with combined pages - this is done on their backend and they produce a pdf from that. I never actually see it.